# jquery validation to check text contains no html

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

How can I perform jquery validation to check if a textarea contains no html tags? (error if it does)

(BTW I am preventing html from coming through on the server anyway)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use John Resig's HTML parser ([here](https://johnresig.com/files/htmlparser.js)), or maybe a more naive solution that just looks for opening tags.

```
$('textarea').each(function() {
   if ($(this).val().match(/<(\w+)((?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:(?:"[^"]*")|(?:'[^']*')|[^>\s]+))?)*)\s*(\/?)>/)) {
      alert('html found');
   }
});
```

Neal's solution suffers from false positives on textareas that contain valid jquery selectors, such as a textarea that contains just "a".

Comment: for some reason, Neals answer did not work for me - no idea why. i know he gave an example too. this worked for me.

Comment: @Neal's solution should work, the false positives notwithstanding, if you use `var text = $(this).val();`.

Comment: ah -okay had to use .val(), got neals solution working too now. thanks

Comment: @raklos. then i wiiin :-p haha. @Neal (me) solution seems much more seamless, but this works as well if u want regex

Comment: @Neal - thanks - I upvoted u. a combination of both answers and comments helped me. wish i could mark both as answers.

Answer (score 10):

try this on for size:

```
$('textarea').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    if($(text).length > 0){
        console.log('contains html elements')
    }
    else {
        console.log('no html elements')
    }
});
```

fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/nSMw4/3/)

Comment: If I may ask, what exactly in that scrpt detects html elements? Obviously Im a newbie. Could that script be modified to strip out html and allow the text in?

Comment: @Brad, that if statement detects in jquery whether there is html in the text or not, and yes, you can strip it out.

Comment: @Brad: It makes use of the jQuery HTML parser/DOM generator. The assumption is: If $(text) produces a set of DOM elements, the input must be HTML. If it doesn't, the input was not HTML. However, think of the following inputs: "#foo", ".bar", "a" - for them all jQuery will return a non-empty list (for the first two only if they accidentelly match any elements on the page) although these inputs are not HTML.

Comment: it does not detect change in value and still refers to the old value that is provided on page load. :-(

Comment: This is longer working (using 1.11). jQuery no throws an error if there is passed a string without valid HTML markup. A `try catch` handler would be needed.